# Access a device in subnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I would like to access the SMB server on Device A [sub-network] from my laptop [main network].

How do I  set up port forwarding for this?
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

From your diagram, it seems your router has a VPN. If that means it is hosting a VPN, you can connect to the VPN of the router and then you will be able to access the whole subnet of your router. This will then let you connect to Device A through the VPN. This is the better option here because you don't expose Device A to your whole network.

If this is not the case, a good option would be to setup a VPN in the ASUS Router's subnet, and then port forward the VPN (usually port 1194/1195) through the ASUS Router. That would let you connect to the VPN and have access to Device A through the IP of device A once connected to the VPN.

If you can't do that, you could setup port forwarding on the Asus Router so it forwards Device A through. This would let you use the routers IP to connect to SMB. This may end up being a bit messy however, because you will have to port forward all the different ports for SMB and also is harder to do for the more devices you have because you will have to port forward every port.

Comment: Hi Toffee, Thanks for your answer. I was actually trying the last option you mentioned (Port forwarding the different SMB ports). I found from internet that SMB ports are in 139 and 445 and tried to set it up - But with no luck. Do you know of any guidelines on how to set-up the port forwarding between two of my routers? I even tried disabling the VPN in my ASUS router -  But still no luck :( I couldn't even ping to my ASUS router

Comment: Samba isn't really meant for port forwarding. I would look up a guide on how to do that if you want, but SMB doesn't play nicely with port forwarding. I assume there is something in the configuration you will need to change.